# **UnicodeDecodeError:** 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 701: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I'm getting this error while reading a .csv dataset.

What am I doing wrong? I think it might be formatting in the dataset, please help.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

data = pd.read_csv('ToyotaCorolla.csv')
```

### Error:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/2k/3rl09_j56yl69kjcwv21q6h80000gn/T/ipykernel_93928/3162765464.py in 
5 from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
6
----> 7 data = pd.read_csv('ToyotaCorolla.csv')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
312
313         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
676     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
677
--> 678     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
679
680

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
573
574     # Create the parser.
--> 575     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
576
577     if chunksize or iterator:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
930
931         self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 932         self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
933
934     def close(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _make_engine(self, f, engine)
1232
1233         try:
-> 1234             return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
1235         except Exception:
1236             if self.handles is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
73
74         kwds["dtype"] = ensure_dtype_objs(kwds.get("dtype", None))
---> 75         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
76
77         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 701: invalid start byte

Comment: Please check the encoding of the csv file, and use the corresponding encoding with  **read_csv**  function, or convert the file encoding to  utf-8, then run your code.